# Area of triangle. Are there two solutions?

Tags: geometry

In a right angled triangle there are sides a, b, and c at 500, 538.52, and 200 units respectively. The angle opposite of c, the 200 unit side is 10.7 degrees.

So using the rule in which the area of the triangle is 1/2absinC, the area of the triangle should be...

0.5*500*528.52*sin10.7

but that gives a result of 24996, which is the wrong answer because if we simply find the area using (200*500)/2 we get 50000.

Please explain.

Comment: That triangle is overdetermined.  For those lengths the angles are $(69.198, 21.801, 90.001)$ so your $50000$, while very close, is not exact.  But the $10.7$ is simply wrong.

Comment: The angle is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\arctan \frac{200}{500}=21.8°$$

[image]

thus the area is given by

$$A\approx \frac12\cdot500\cdot 538.52\cdot\sin 21.8°$$

Comment: What does arctan mean?

Comment: is the function inverse of tan, it is used to calculate the angle given the sides